# Mongodb last access of an obj

Tags: php, mongodb

I used an insert command on mongodb table as

```
db.test.insert( { users: [ 10341, 106, 109, 108 ]});
```

snapshot of table is :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591589df75552bb222a4b2bf"), "users" : [ 10341, 106, 109, 108 ] }
```

To access last value of users i.e 108, we are using

```
db.test.find({users:10341},{users:1, _id:0})
```

and I am getting

```
{ "users" : [ 10341, 106, 109, 108 ] }
```

and then in my phpcode and parsing this object.

Is there any way that from mongodb, i can get 108.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use {slice: -1} wich will return only the last item of the array:

```
db.test.find({users: 10341}, {_id: 0, users: {$slice: -1}})
```

output:

```
{ "users" : [ 108 ] }
```

Comment: @Brain Teasers $slice doesn't no scan document, it's a projection operator, so it just return the last item of an array